# Signleton constructor executed multiple times in NextJS 13 middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, singleton

I have a simple singleton named `Paths`:

```js
export default class Paths {
  private static _instance: Paths;

  private constructor() {
    console.log('paths constructor');
  }

  public static get Instance() {
    console.log(this._instance);
    return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
  }
}
```

And a simple NextJS middleware:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import Paths from './lib/features/paths';

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const paths = Paths.Instance;

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

However, when i refresh the page, the server console logs this:

```bash
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
undefined
paths constructor
```

Meaning the constructor is executed multiple times.

What's the reason and how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

This is a `next dev` issue. If you `build` and `start`, you only have one `console.log`.